# jQuery callback in .hover callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I am trying to remove an appended element after I have hidden the element on mouse out. What have I done wrong with the callback in the .hover callback?

```
// START OF $(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function ()

$('.custom-right-boxes a').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="click-here"><b>Click</b><span>Here</span></div>');
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '88px',
        height: '58px',
        marginLeft: '-44px',
        marginTop: '-40px'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    });
}, function () {
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '0px',
        height: '0px',
        marginLeft: '-0px',
        marginTop: '-0px'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    }),

    function () {
        $('.click-here').remove();
    };
});


// END OF $(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: you have a `)` in the wrong place toward the end.

Comment: Include what is not working. What is working etc. Help the community to help you.

Comment: What I mean is that the animationall works, but the $('.click-here').remove(); bit doesn't. Have I got it in the wrong place? I want it to be removed AFTER the animate to make all values 0px finishes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it guys! Thanks for everyone that helped. Basically the bit Nelson told me was crucial so thanks for that, I also had to change:-

,{
        duration: 300
}

simply to:-

,300

And then the callback worked :-) This was the final code (before I made additional changes):-

```
// START OF $(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function () {

$('.custom-right-boxes a').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="click-here"><b>Click</b><span>Here</span></div>');
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '88px',
        height: '58px',
        marginLeft: '-44px',
        marginTop: '-40px'
    }, 300);

}, function () {
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '0px',
        height: '0px',
        marginLeft: '-0px',
        marginTop: '-0px'
    }, 300, function () {
        $('.click-here').remove();
    });

});

// END OF $(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code fix these:

```
}, {
        duration: 300
    }),  //--> REMOVE THIS parens

    function () {
        $('.click-here').remove();
    };  //ADD A PARENS HERE, like });
```

As you were incorrectly passing the third parameter to `animate()` , which is the callback function. Made above noted changes and try it.

This would be the corrected version:

```
// START OF $(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function (){

$('.custom-right-boxes a').hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="click-here"><b>Click</b><span>Here</span></div>');
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '88px',
        height: '58px',
        marginLeft: '-44px',
        marginTop: '-40px'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    });
}, function () {
    $('.click-here').stop().animate({
        width: '0px',
        height: '0px',
        marginLeft: '-0px',
        marginTop: '-0px'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    },

    function () {
        $('.click-here').remove();
    });
});


// END OF $(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. The animate works fine as before but the di isn't being removed afterwards :-(